# Mocking via stretchr/testify, different return args

Tags: go, mocking, testify

Function below describes how to mock using testify. `args.Bool(0)`, `args.Error(1)` are mocked positional return values.

```
func (m *MyMockedObject) DoSomething(number int) (bool, error) {

  args := m.Called(number)
  return args.Bool(0), args.Error(1)

}
```

**Is it possible to return anything other than** `args.Int()`, `args.Bool()`, `args.String()`? What if I need to return `int64`, or a custom `struct`. Is there a method or am I missing something?

For example:

```
func (m *someMock) doStuff(p *sql.DB, id int) (res int64, err error)
```

Comment: Go does not support overloading of user-defined functions on the return types nor the arguments. However you can use two functions with different names.

Comment: and this is not about overloading it is about testify library

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `args.Get` and type assertion.

From the [docs](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/mock/doc.go#L38-L40):

```
// For objects of your own type, use the generic Arguments.Get(index) method and make a type assertion:
//
//     return args.Get(0).(*MyObject), args.Get(1).(*AnotherObjectOfMine)
```

So, your example would be:

```golang
func (m *someMock) doStuff(p *sql.DB, id int) (res int64, err error) {
    args := m.Called(p, id)
    return args.Get(0).(int64), args.Error(1)
}
```

Additionaly, if your return value is a pointer (e.g. pointer to struct), you should check if it is nil before performing type assertion.